# Trying to connect to a rtsp stream using gstreamer library

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to create a rtsp stream from a static mp4 video  by infinite looping it using ffmpeg, using the cmd

```
ffmpeg  -flush_packets 1 -re -stream_loop -1 -i sample.mp4 -f rtsp rtsp://ip:8554/mystream
```

And now I want to read it using the gstreamer library, but when I try to read it using the cmd,

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip:8554/mystream
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip:8554/mystream ! avdec_h264 ! autovideoconvert ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! autovideosink
```

I get this error,

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://10.0.0.19:8554/mystream
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
./grammar.y(510): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstRTSPSrc named rtspsrc0 to some pad of avdec_h264 named avdec_h264-0
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(5653): gst_rtspsrc_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
Execution ended after 0:00:01.552277296
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

After using cmd,

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip:8554/mystream ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,clock-rate=90000 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videorate ! videoconvert ! queue! autovideosink
```

Updated logs with Error ,

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://10.0.0.19:8554/mystream
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
0:00:02.180429398  3554 0x7f1cdc04e230 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:02.180465192  3554 0x7f1cdc04e230 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
0:00:03.316770515  3554 0x7f1cdc032b20 WARN                 default grammar.y:510:gst_parse_no_more_pads:<rtspsrc0> warning: Delayed linking failed.
0:00:03.316823812  3554 0x7f1cdc032b20 WARN                 default grammar.y:510:gst_parse_no_more_pads:<rtspsrc0> warning: failed delayed linking some pad of GstRTSPSrc named rtspsrc0 to some pad of GstRtpH264Depay named rtph264depay0
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
./grammar.y(510): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstRTSPSrc named rtspsrc0 to some pad of GstRtpH264Depay named rtph264depay0
0:00:04.018867523  3554 0x7f1cdc04e280 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc3> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:04.018937057  3554 0x7f1cdc04e280 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc3> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc3: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc3:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
Execution ended after 0:00:01.908870388
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to N
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: were you able to resolve this error, i am getting the same error in newer version of gstreamer (1.22), it works in 1.16 but i need some plugins and features which are available in  latest release.

Answer (score 0):

RTSP streams media over RTP, before decoding video stream, rtp depayloading is required.

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip:8554/mystream !  application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,clock-rate=90000 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videorate ! videoconvert ! queue! autovideosink

dot digram of gst-play-1.0 rtsp://ip:8554/mystream may give you a better picture.

Comment: Getting another error after using your cmd , I have updated it in the question!.

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip:8554/mystream ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,clock-rate=90000 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videorate ! videoconvert ! queue! autovideosink --gst-debug=2
Can you share the debug logs?

Or verbose mode of rtspstream may help to find the stream type
 gst-play-1.0 rtsp://ip:8554/mystream -v

Comment: Updated logs in question!